# Negative or decimal

Tags: java

Hi guys i just want to know what is the problem of my code but i think i've getting some logic errors
 this would be the out put of the program

```
"Enter a float values: -4.6

 Do you want the (s)quare or square (r)oot of -4.6: r

 You must have a positive for square root.

 Do you want the (s)quare or square (r)oot of -4.6: s

 The number -4.6 squared has the value 21.159999122619638

 Do you want to enter more data ? y/n: n .
```

//============================================================

This is the logic error i got .

```
Enter a float values: -4

Do you want the (s)quare or square (r)oot of -4.0: s

You must have a positive for square root.

Do you want the (s)quare or square (r)oot of -4.0: s

The number -4.0 squared has the value 16.0

Do you want to enter more data ? y/n:
```

Supposed to be i will be getting the squared of the value instead of getting the statement" You must have a positive for a square " that won't be really necessary to happen because i did not chose R to "Square root the -4:
hope you understand and help me .. 
This is the logic error i got .

Like this , this should be the correct answer .

```
Enter a float values: -4

Do you want the (s)squared or square (r)root of -4.0: s

The number -4.0 squared has the value 16.0

Do you want to enter more data ? y/n:
```

thanks guys . I'll be waiting for your answers and help

BTW this is the code ^^

```
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

    float FloatValue;
    char again = 'y';
    char letter;

    String token;
    String SqrSqrt; 

    do 

    {

        System.out.print("Enter a float values: ");
        FloatValue = console.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Do you want the (s)quare or square (r)oot of " + FloatValue +": ");
        SqrSqrt = console.next();

        if (FloatValue < 0)
        {
        System.out.println("You must have a positive for square root.");


        System.out.print("Do you want the (s)quare or square (r)oot of " + FloatValue +": ");
        SqrSqrt = console.next();

        }


    switch(SqrSqrt)

        {

        case "r":   

        {

            System.out.println("The square root of " + FloatValue +" is " +  Math.sqrt(FloatValue) );       
            break;
        }   

        case "s":

            System.out.println("The number " + FloatValue +" squared has the value " +  Math.pow(FloatValue , 2) );
            break;  

        }

    System.out.print("\nDo you want to enter more data ? y/n: ");
        token = console.next();
        again = token.charAt(0);

        }
    while ( again == 'y');  
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your system locale? Does it use `,` as the decimal separator?

Comment: You can simply change `if (FloatValue < 0)` this to `while(FloatValue < 0)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above one approach i am giving second approach to solve this.

main issue is in your if condition that should be changed to loop.

instead of :

```
 if (FloatValue < 0)
    {
    System.out.println("You must have a positive for square root.");
    System.out.print("Do you want the (s)quare or square (r)oot of " + FloatValue +": ");
    SqrSqrt = console.next();

    }
```

you can write :

```
 while( ! ("s".equalsIgnoreCase(SqrSqrt)) && FloatValue < 0)
    {
    System.out.println("You must have a positive for square root.");
    System.out.print("Do you want the (s)quare or square (r)oot of " + FloatValue +": ");
    SqrSqrt = console.next();

    }
```

Comment: I wish just once someone would address me "sir" without adding "you're making a scene"

Comment: Thank you for those who help me . and sharing there ideas . it helps me a lot guys and i learn something new here . although I'm only a beginner here to ask .

Comment: @Poldie I'm sorry because that is the way of how i show respect to a person . i dont mean to offend anyone or make a scene . i just use sir as showing respect to a person hope you understand and it will happen again .

Answer (score 0):

Your flow is wrong.  The problem is once you get your input you are checking if its less than 0. If yes you are printing the message `You must have a positive for square root.` (even if user really wanted to perform `square`) Instead do that checking only is user selects `r` option.

Change like this

```
do 
{

  System.out.print("Enter a float values: ");
  FloatValue = console.nextFloat();

  System.out.print("Do you want the (s)quare or square (r)oot of " + FloatValue +": ");
        SqrSqrt = console.next();


switch(SqrSqrt)
{
 case "r":   


   if (FloatValue < 0)
   {
       System.out.println("You must have a positive for square root.");
   } 
   else
      System.out.println("The square root of " + FloatValue +" is " +  Math.sqrt(FloatValue) );       
            break;


 case "s":    
            System.out.println("The number " + FloatValue +" squared has the value " +  Math.pow(FloatValue , 2) );
            break;  

}

    System.out.print("\nDo you want to enter more data ? y/n: ");
        token = console.next();
        again = token.charAt(0);

        }
    while ( again == 'y');
```

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh it was because of first if condition. that should be loop.

Comment: @Prashant If we change into loop,then what if user enters `-4` and wants to perform `square` operation. Then it will never go to the `switch`. The check(`if<0`) must be inside `case r`

Comment: he can check that also by putting one more condition **while( ! ("s".equalsIgnoreCase(SqrSqrt)) && FloatValue < 0)** @user7

Comment: @Prashant Yes, it can be done. Your approch: If user enters a `negative `number and chooses `r` you loop till he enters a `positive` one. My code considers it as `invalid` and goes back for user input again.

Comment: Sir the requirment is to output when i put a negative value like 
 -4.6 and the prompt ask me i what Method should i use is it to Square the -4.6 or to Square root the -4.6 and if i choose square root it should say that i should have a positive and it will ask me again to enter a method if it's either to Square the negative or to Square Root . and if you choose square then it will display the result of negative value being Square

Comment: @AdrianAbrasaldo  `it will ask me again to enter a method` Why? If input is negative only one more method(`square`) is there. So why unnecessarily ask input from user..OR in other words why wait till user enters `s`

Comment: @AdrianAbrasaldo If input is negative and if user chooses `r` print the `message` and perform `square operation` on the input. Or As my code does go back and get input again

Comment: Sir the requirment is to output when i put a negative value like 
 -4.6 and the prompt ask me i what Method should i use is it to Square the -4.6 or to Square root the -4.6 and if i choose square root it should say that i should have a positive

Comment: and it will ask me again to enter a method if it's either to Square the negative or to Square Root . and if you choose square then it will display the result of negative value being Square .. then another input of a negative value like -4 and again if the prompt ask me what i want to use it's either Square root the -4 or Squared the -4 if i choose the Squared then it the prompt should display the output squared not to say that i need a positive number for square root . that should never really necessary to say it because i already choose the (S)quared to Squared the -4.

Comment: @AdrianAbrasaldo The code that I have provided does not print message stating that input is negative when you enter `-4` and choose `s`

Comment: yes sir that was my point if the value is negative then ask the user to enter again if it's (S)quare or Square (R)oot and it's obviously to enter the (s)quared so finally the prompt will display the result

Comment: is there any way to print the message that you need to enter a (S)quare for the negative value instead of Square root the Negative value ?

Comment: @AdrianAbrasaldo Ok. But I don't really see any use in doing like that. Anyway there is a answer given by Prashant that will do as you told.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh  I'm stuck at this problem i don't want to skip this because i want to finish it without any logic errors . but i have no idea how to change it or add any code right now so i really freaking need your help guys ..
Btw thank you for helping me

Comment: @Prashant  I'm stuck at this problem i don't want to skip this because i want to finish it without any logic errors . but i have no idea how to change it or add any code right now so i really freaking need your help guys .. Btw thank you for helping m

Comment: @user7 but our professor is very particular of the output . it should be like that because we follow the instructions in the book . so that would be never be an excuse for our professor .

Comment: @AdrianAbrasaldo I've already told you. See Prashanth's answer. It will suit your need. I don't want to edit my answer to an already existing one. If you don't want to print `square/square root` when number is negative change the 2nd print to something like `please enter square since the number is negative`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to obvious errors, I would like to remind that Java does not have built in complex number support. You can not just `Sqrt(-4)` it would just return NaN (acronym for: **N**ot **a** **N**umber). Furthermore diferent locales have different numbering formats (Ex: US uses "." and FF uses "," as decimal separator), by default Java uses your system locale.

If you would like to get result as 2 decimal place number as a String view using US locale:

```
public static String GetSqrt(double x) {
    return String.format(x < 0.0 ? "%.2fi" : "%.2f", Math.sqrt(-x), Locale.US);
}
```

Assuming you are a beginner here is a demo:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        double x=-4;
        System.out.println(String.format("sqrt(%.2f) is "+ GetSqrt(x), x));
    }
    public static String GetSqrt(double x) {
        return String.format(x < 0.0 ? "%.2fi" : "%.2f", Math.sqrt(-x), Locale.US);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... In case you still did not find your solution or If you are looking for a more structured approach for this problem, I think you should do it by breaking the problem into smaller problems and defining a function responsible for each of these smaller problems.

Now use these smaller chunks to solve the problem.

In this case your problem can be broken into following,

1. Ask for the float input.
2. Ask for operation : "r" or "s"
3. Check if the operation is appropriate, and re-ask if not.
4. Calculate and Print the result.
5. Ask for user choice to continue, go to step one if yes.

You can do it in a structured way as shown below,

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SquareOrRoot {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner( System.in );

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        askFloatAndPerform();
        askAgain();
    }

    public static void askAgain() {
        System.out.print("\nDo you want to enter more data ? y/n: ");
        String token = console.next();
        char again = token.charAt(0);
        if ( again == 'y' ) {
            askFloatAndPerform();
            askAgain();
        }
    }

    public static void askFloatAndPerform() {
        System.out.print( "Enter a float values: " );
        float floatVal = console.nextFloat();

        // this will keep asking untill we have a proper oper
        String oper = checkOper( floatVal, "" );

        switch( oper ) {
            case "r":
                System.out.println( "The square root of " + floatVal + " is " +  Math.sqrt( floatVal ) );
            case "s":
                System.out.println( "The number " + floatVal + " squared has the value " +  Math.pow( floatVal , 2) );
        }

    }

    public static String checkOper( float floatVal, String oper ) {
        if( oper.equalsIgnoreCase( "r" ) && floatVal < 0 ) {
            System.out.println("You must have a positive for square root.");
            // ask for oper again
            oper = askOper( floatVal );
            // check it again
            oper = checkOper( floatVal, oper );
        }
        else if( oper.equalsIgnoreCase( "s" ) ){
            // Do nothing, oper is allright
        }
        // If anything other than "r" or "s"
        else {
            // ask for oper again
            oper = askOper( floatVal );
            // check it again
            oper = checkOper( floatVal, oper );
        }
        // By now the oper should be allright
        return oper;
    }

    public static String askOper( float floatVal ) {
        System.out.print( "Do you want the (s)quare or square (r)oot of " + floatVal +": " );
        String oper = console.next();
        return oper;
    }

}
```

I think comments should explain the code but if you don't understand something, ask away.